# UnicodeEncode error in python when uploading CSV file to postgres DB

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, encode

I keep getting a UnicodeEncode error when trying to upload a CSV file into a Postgres DB using Python2.7

First I create the file in CSV format. The file has non latin characters that's why I download it and encoding the second column which it has strings:

```
writer = csv.writer(response, dialect='excel')
writer.writerow(tuple(corresponding_data[btn]["columns"].split(',')))

 for row in rows:
        field_1 = row[0]
        field_2 = row[1].encode(encoding='UTF-8')
        fields = [field_1, field_2]
        writer.writerows([fields])
```

The file is created without errors. When I open it in Excel I see that there are some values like: Dajï¿*ï¿*

In order to upload the file and save it in a table in Postgres I use the python module called: CSVKit.

This is what I do:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(absolute_base_file, 'rb', encoding='utf-8')
delimiter = ","
no_header_row = False
try:
    csv_table = table.Table.from_csv(f, name=table_name_temp, no_header_row=no_header_row, delimiter=delimiter)
```

Although I specify the encoding I keep getting an error:

```
<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>
```

I don't know what else to try here.

**EDITED**

After checking the values in the DB I see they dont really have any not latin characters but there are values with white spaces that when I save them they get unicoded (the whitespaces).
I think this is what is causing the issue.

Comment: I remember having troubles with unicode in py file - try adding `# coding=utf-8` to the very first row of a script

Comment: I already have that!

Comment: and this method `table.Table.from_csv` - from where?

Comment: Its from CSVKit module https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/api/csvkit.html

Comment: Guys I think its related with white spaces in my database table. Could it be they cause the issue?

Comment: what database encoding are you using?

Comment: I have uploaded the tables in postgresql using the shptopgsql tool and encoding: LATIN1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I have flattened the values before I write them into the CSV.
I used the unidecode module as following:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

for row in rows:
        field_1 = row[0]
        field_2 = unidecode(row[1]).encode(encoding='UTF-8') # LINE CHANGED
        fields = [field_1, field_2]
        writer.writerows([fields])
    return response
```

Although not a permanent solution, this solved my issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.0) instead of the built-in `csv`